# Computer screen glitched, can't boot normally

Tags: windows-7, boot, bsod

When I was using my laptop, my screen went crazy and I got BSOD.
Now I can not boot it normally but can boot in Safe Mode & Networking (haven't tried Command Prompt one).

I've tried System Restore, last known working state(?), uninstalling and reinstalling video driver but still no luck. My device manager also seems OK. There are no yellow triangles or anything.

[image: This is a screenshot taken with Snipping Tool]

And these are what I see.

[image: BSOD]

Safe Mode Loading:
[image]

Browsing in Safe Mode:
[image]

I have no idea what happened or how to fix this. Hoping that you guys can help.

I am using HP Pavilion dv6 (around 6-years old laptop), Win7 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a hardware problem, probably video RAM. Try a different, known-good video adapter.

If you can't (because it's built into the laptop), then you're now in the market for trying to find a [compatible motherboard from eBay](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/hp-pavilion-dv6000-motherboard) or alike, or just replacing the laptop.